# How to change the color of selected columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

This is my working example of my Amchart.

[code pen working demo](http://codepen.io/RKR3/pen/WoLeMZ)

I want to change the color of the first four columns.

I know I can change colors by giving the color as a property in the JSON file.

```
  "color":"hex code"
```

Is there another way to change the color?

I want to achieve something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking for a way to set individual column colors without specifying a [`lineColorField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineColorField) and/or [`fillColorsField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillColorsField) in your graph and data, then there isn't a way to do this. In case you meant to use either of those fields, this is how you would do it:

```
  "dataProvider": [{
    "day": 3,
    "zone_id": 2,
    "short_trips": 40,
    "long_trips": 60,
    "columnColor": "#00cc00",
  }, {
    "day": 3,
    "zone_id": 3,
    "short_trips": 30,
    "long_trips": 30,
    "columnColor": "#00cc00",
  }, {
    "day": 3,
    "zone_id": 4,
    "short_trips": 40,
    "long_trips": 60,
    "columnColor": "#00cc00",
  }, {
    "day": 3,
    "zone_id": 5,
    "short_trips": 90,
    "long_trips": 60
     // no color specified, use default color
  }, 
  // ...
],
"graphs": [{
  "fillColorsField": "columnColor",
  // ...
}]
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/891d7a6ddc59361f4f9072485e4616cc/?editors=0010)

Comment: ya I know that I can do it in this manner but my JSON data does not contain the columnColor becuse it is retrieved from the  database and loaded to the chart.can I do like the image in the question?

Comment: Like I said, you can't do this without specifying it in your JSON data. That's your only option. There's nothing stopping you from adding this field before loading it into the chart according to whatever logic your situation dictates.

Answer (score 0):

You mean without using the color property in the *javascript* file?

I'll be honest, I have no idea the right way to use Amchart, but if your demo is any indication, you can just set the path tag's fill property for all the bars in your css file.

[image]